# How to emit 2 Observables and avoid returning anything

Tags: java, java-8, rx-java, vert.x

I'm trying to emit 2 Observables using .zip() method but I would like to avoid the need to return anything due to the use of Func2.

Is there something like that??

I can't find any other method that does that...

Thank you!

**EDIT:**

```
Observable<> obs1 = ...;
Observable<> obs2 = ...;

Observable.zip(obs1, obs2, new Func2<T1, T2, R>() {

    R call(T1 t1, T2 t2) {
        ..
    }
    ..
   return ...;
});
```

I would like a function like zip but one that doesn't require you to return anything - for example Action2 instead of Func2.

Comment: What do you mean by _"emit 2 Observalbes"_ ? 2 items in the resulting observable  or 2 Observables in the resulting observable  ? Could you show a marble diagram ?

Comment: I have never used RxJava, but have you tried just passing `Void` as the third type argument and simply returning `null`?

Comment: I don't think there's a better way, in my opinion just return `Observable.empty()` or an ok status like `Observable.just("OK")`

Comment: Brice: I will try your solution!

Comment: What are you trying to do with the values within the call? If you aren't actually returning anything, it sounds like you are creating a side effect within the call. If that's the case, there's likely a cleaner way.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved using `toCompletable()` as provided in the example below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Observable.just(1).zipWith(Observable.just(2), (a, b)->a+b).toCompletable().subscribe(()->System.out.println("done"));
}
```